# Android firebase failed build.gradle implementation

Tags: android, firebase

I'm in the final stages putting my project on cloud firebase.  Added all required firebase requirements using the firebase console. The Android compile fails with the error: Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:.
This is a copy of the implementation in the build.gradle file:

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'

Is this the correct statement for these dependencies?  I assume there is no version number.  This project is my first attempt putting a project on the cloud firebase.  Appreciate any help.
Roger

Comment: Have you added the BoM dependency?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider?authuser=0#install-sdk

You don’t need to specify version only if you also defined BoM dependency. Otherwise version is required.

```
dependencies {
// Declare the dependency for the App Check library
// When NOT using the BoM, you must specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:16.0.0'
}
```